# How to update an array in useState using its index in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am having trouble when updating an array using the useState hook. What i want is i have an array filled with n number of elements where n could be 1-10. and i want to update the value of an element using its index no. but i am not getting any help. Here's the codes what i want to acheive:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import React, {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const myScreen = props => {
const [myCustomArray, setmyCustomArray] = useState(Array.(5).fill(0));

const onClickHandler = (n) => {
// update the element in array having the index no. n
setMyCustomArray([n] = 'something');
}
```

But this approach is not helping me. Anyone have better approach?

Comment: Have you tried to use map() function on your array? it take 2 argument the element of array and its index

Comment: Yes, i use the array.map function as well. but that didn't help me, what i want is i want to update that array, without using forloop as this will throw re-render errors and will slow down my codes. any other approach for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should spread the array before that

```js
const onClickHandler = (n) => {
    const arr = [...myCustomArray];
    arr[n] = 'something';
    setMyCustomArray(arr);
}
```

react checks the reference of the array, if changed then rerender, else don't.

Comment: That work like charm but i am getting the error of too many re-render.